# Can the Log-Rank Test be used for feature selection?

Tags: r, survival, chi-squared-test, feature-selection, logrank-test

Chi-squared can be used to test independence and if independence is present, the variable can be dropped.

Does the log-rank test work the same way since it is tied closely to the chi-squared test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logrank test is used to test the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the populations in the probability of an event at any time point. It is most likely to detect a difference between groups when the risk of an event is consistently greater for one group than another. So it is a purely significance test which cannot provide an estimate of the size of the difference between the groups or a confidence interval. [1]

So I don't think it is used for feature selection. It is used for survival analysis.

---

Sources:

- [The logrank test](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC403858/) [1]